# For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ 6x= 0$ , there is a fault in the logic behind the solving of the inequality below. Can you identify what it is?

Tags: inequality

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ 6x= 0$ , there is a fault in the logic behind the solving
of the inequality below. Can you identify what it is?

$$4 \geq \frac{8}{x} \Rightarrow 4x \geq 8 \Rightarrow x \geq 2 $$

Comment: x not equal to 0

Comment: In the question $6x=0$ ?

Comment: If $6x=0$ then $x=0$ and you should be ashamed for even writing down $\frac 8x$.

Comment: sorry typing mistake 6x = 0 . It should be x is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

When $x<0$, $4\geq {8\over x}\implies 4x\leq 8$ instead.